# Как при клике на следующий элемент сделать предыдущий неактивным

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужна такая карта https://irobot.ru/contacts/

```
<ul id="map-hover">
  <li id="area01" ><span class="title"><span>Центральный</span></span></li>
  <li id="area02" ><span class="title"><span>Приволжский</span></span></li>
  <li id="area03" ><span class="title"><span>Казахстан</span></span></li>
</ul>


function map(n) {
  $('li:nth-child(' + n + ') .title span').on('click', function (){
    $('#map-hover li:nth-child(' + n + ')').addClass('active activestate');
  });
}
var li = $('#map-hover li');
for (var i = 0; i <= li.length; i++) {
  map(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала надо удалить этот класс со всех элементов, а потом проставить тому, по которому был клик:

```js
$('#map-hover').on('click', 'li', function() {
 $('#map-hover li').removeClass('active')
 $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active {
 background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="map-hover">
  <li id="area01" ><span class="title"><span>Центральный</span></span></li>
  <li id="area02" ><span class="title"><span>Приволжский</span></span></li>
  <li id="area03" ><span class="title"><span>Казахстан</span></span></li>
</ul>
```